# How check if value true for one facility but false for other facilities

Tags: select, where-clause, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to construct a SelectionFormula in crystal reports that will check, if one facility has true for the alert column, but other facilities have false.  Any that have true and false for the same person's alert, for different facilities, would be included in the report.

For example for the data:

```
Last  First  Facility   Alert
Yoda  Guy    A          true
Yoda  Guy    B          false
Skyw  Luke   A          true
```

I want my report to give me Yoda but not Skyw, and list the facilities Yoda has with his name and the Alert value.

Report wanted:

```
Last  First  Facility   Alert
Yoda  Guy    A          true
Yoda  Guy    B          false
```

Would that be Report=>SelectionFormulas=>record

```
{Facilities.Alert} = true
and
{Facilities.Alert} = false
```

I don't see how to tie-in that it's for the one person in each case.  I think the above would give me the entire list of true and false alerts for all the people.

Would that be in and not in? How would that go? I'm new to crystal. [in and not in](https://www.algorithminc.com/blog/bid/171207/crystal-reports-in-and-not-in-record-selection)

*Update: I tried doing what was in the answer (@millet) below.  I added alias' for each table, and made the link so for facility, it was != between the alias and not alias links.

I added Alert_True for Facility, and Alert_False for Facility_1 (alias), just the fields pulled into the report for alert.

Then, in Report=>SelectionFormulas=>record, I added this:

```
(
({Facilities.Alert} = true) 
or 
({Facilities_1.Alert} = false)
)
```

But it doesn't seem to work either. In the results I see:

```
Last  First  Facility   Alert_True   Alert_False
Yoda  Guy    A          true        true
Yoda  Guy    B          true        true
Yoda  Guy    B          true        false
Yoda  Guy    A          false       false
Skyw  Luke   A          false       false
Skyw  Luke   C          false       false
```

I wanted the report to only show when the alert was true for some facilities but not all, at a minimum.

**Update:
I changed the SelectionFormula to this per comment below and the results look good, but it's not obvious.  I'm not sure how to make the Alert difference more obvious.  I changed this:

```
(
    ({Facilities.Alert} = true) 
    and 
    ({Facilities_1.Alert} = false)
    )
```

The resulting table looks like this (original data may have been modified):

```
Last  First  Facility   Alert_True   Alert_False
Yoda  Guy    A          true        false
Yoda  Guy    B          true        false
Yoda  Guy    C          true        false
Yoda  Guy    D          true        false
Skyw  Luke   A          true       false
Skyw  Luke   C          true       false
Test  TT     H          true       false
Test  TT     H          true       false
```

For some reason it always shows true in the first alert column and false in the second.  When I go to our application and check for the resulting ones found, among the facilities, at least one is always checked and some are not.  However, you can't tell from the results which they are.  For example, for Test above, For facility S he's not checked, but for facility H he's checked, and for facility J he's not checked. But the report only shows facility H for Test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is via table aliases:

Bring the relevant tables a second time into the report (Crystal would ask you to specify an Alias for the 2nd instance of each table).

Add a join condition that the person is the same person but the facility is NOT the same facility

Add a record selection condition on the 1st instance that Alert is True, and for the 2nd instance that Alert is False.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the join in crystal.  I know how to do that in sql but not crystal.

Comment: I did the links.  Is that a join in crystal?

Comment: So that would be a link with not equal for facilities?

Comment: Could you give more info on the "record selection condition on the 1st instance that Alert is True, and for the 2nd instance that Alert is False"

Comment: Do you mean this:   (
({Facilities.Alert} = true) 
or 
({Facilities_1.Alert} = false)
)

Comment: That can't be it.  That would always be the same. What do you mean?

Comment: see what I tried in the question above. It doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: {Facilities.Alert} = true AND {Facilities_1.Alert} = false

Comment: How does it know that it's comparing separate facilities' alerts?  I know I set up my link between the facility and facility_1 table as !=, but can you explain how that's finding the people who have facilities where it's only checked for some?

Comment: I understand better now.  Thanks @MilletSoftware.